# Convert Date & Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hv the following table :-

[image]

I need to convert it into:-

[image]

Do take note that the date of TIMEINA must follow exactly as per TIMEIN1. As for the time, it will be fixed ie 7.30AM, 8.30AM etc.

I tried the below SQL but it doesn’t work:-

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Added the sql-server tag, because this is clearly SQL Server syntax.

Comment: what is the data type of TIMEIN1 and TIMEINA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your code as code and not as an image.

In any case, your code is comparing a `datetime` to a `time` value.  Just do a conversion.  Instead of `timein1 between . . .`, use:

```
cast(timein1 as time) between . . .
```

EDIT:

Oh, you also need to get the full date out.  For that, use arithmetic on `datetime`:

```
cast('07:30:00' as datetime) + cast(cast(timein1 as date) as datetime)
```

The double `cast` on `timein1` is just to remove the time component.

Comment: Ok, that will get me to 7.30AM, 8.30AM etc. However, I still need to hv the date, in this format YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS format. The date is based on TIMEIN1.

Comment: it's ok but there are some little issues. For eg, TIMEIN1 is 20131208 00:00:00 will be reflected as 1900-01-01 00:00:00. I need it to be 20131208 00:00:00. BTW, the results are in YYYY-MM-DD. How can I change it to YYYMMDD ?

Comment: ok, I hv fixed the 1900-01-01 00:00:00 issue but how can I maintain it as YYYMMDD format.

Comment: You can use `convert()` to convert the `datetime` back to whatever format you want.

Comment: I tried convert(varchar(8),timein1,112) but it is still shown as YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 2):

The main question I have is how many queries are going against this table?

If you are doing this complex logic in one report, then by all means use a SELECT.

But it is crying out to me for a better solution.

**Why not use computed column?**

Since it is a date and non-deterministic, you can not use the persisted key word to physically store the calculated value.

However, you will only have this code in the table definition, not in every query.

I did the case for the first two ranges and two sample date items.  The rest is up to you.!

```
-- Just play
use tempdb;
go

-- Drop table
if object_id('time_clock') > 0
drop table time_clock
go

-- Create table
create table time_clock
(
    tc_id int,
    tc_day char(3),
    tc_time_in datetime,
    tc_time_out datetime,
    tc_division char(3),
    tc_empid char(5),

    -- Use computed column
    tc_time_1 as
    (
    case 

      -- range 1
      when 
        tc_division = 'KEP' and 
        cast(tc_time_in as time) between '04:30:00' and '07:29:59'
      then 
        cast((convert(char(10), tc_time_in, 101) + ' 07:30:00') as datetime)

      -- range 2
      when 
        tc_division = 'KEP' and 
        cast(tc_time_in as time) between '17:30:00' and '19:29:59'
      then 
        cast((convert(char(10), tc_time_in, 101) + ' 19:30:00') as datetime)

      -- no match
      else NULL
    end
    ) 
);

-- Load store products
insert into time_clock values
(1,'SUN', '20131201 06:53:57', '20131201 16:23:54', 'KEP', 'A007'),
(2,'TUE', '20131201 18:32:42', '20131201 03:00:47', 'KEP', 'A007');

-- Show the data
select * from time_clock
```

Expected results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this script might helps you.

```
print replace(convert(nvarchar(25) , getdate(), 120), '-', '') -- yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss
print replace(convert(nvarchar(25) , getdate(), 102), '.', '') -- yyyyMMdd
print convert(nvarchar(25) , getdate(), 108) -- HH:mm:ss
```

HERE is the T-SQL

```
SELECT  [Day],
        TIMEIN1,
        TIMEOUT1,
        DIVISION,
        EMPLOYEE,

        --IF TIMEIN1 is varchar
        LEFT(TIMEIN1, 9) +
        CASE
            WHEN DIVISION = 'KEP' AND RIGHT(TIMEIN1, 8) BETWEEN '04:30:00' AND '07:29:59'
                THEN '07:30:00'
            WHEN DIVISION = 'KEP' AND RIGHT(TIMEIN1, 8) BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '19:29:59'
                THEN '19:30:00'
            WHEN DIVISION = 'SER' AND RIGHT(TIMEIN1, 8) BETWEEN '04:30:00' AND '08:29:59'
                THEN '08:30:00'
            WHEN DIVISION = 'SER' AND RIGHT(TIMEIN1, 8) BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '20:29:59'
                THEN '20:30:00'
            ELSE '00:00:00'
        END AS TIMEINA


        --IF TIMEIN1 is Date Time
        , replace(convert(nvarchar(25) , TIMEIN1, 102), '.', '') + ' ' +
        CASE
            WHEN DIVISION = 'KEP' AND convert(nvarchar(25) , TIMEIN1, 108) BETWEEN '04:30:00' AND '07:29:59'
                THEN '07:30:00'
            WHEN DIVISION = 'KEP' AND convert(nvarchar(25) , TIMEIN1, 108) BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '19:29:59'
                THEN '19:30:00'
            WHEN DIVISION = 'SER' AND convert(nvarchar(25) , TIMEIN1, 108) BETWEEN '04:30:00' AND '08:29:59'
                THEN '08:30:00'
            WHEN DIVISION = 'SER' AND convert(nvarchar(25) , TIMEIN1, 108) BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '20:29:59'
                THEN '20:30:00'
            ELSE '00:00:00'
        END AS TIMEINA

FROM    tempdb.dbo.TSA
```

[check this for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)